# Numpy broken in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, python, numpy

I have installed the package `python-numpy` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Unfortunately, the package is broken:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
 from . import add_newdocs
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
 from .type_check import *
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
 from . import multiarray
 ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Does Python often get broken in Ubuntu? Numpy is a pretty basic package.

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? I have no problem with numpy. What is your python and numpy version?

Comment: Sorry for message. I found the problem. I was using the wrong python since I had installed anaconda. Removing anaconda make the system works

Comment: @MathieuDutourSikiric You should write an answer to let others on the site know how you solved your problem. And no, it is not frequent to have `numpy` broken on Ubuntu if you knew how to install it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, simply because my LD_LIBRARY_PATH included a directory with an incompatible Openblas

Comment: VTR because this is yet another example of the perils of using Anaconda in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

- OP solved the problem:

  > ...I found the problem. I was using the wrong python since I had
  >   installed [anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)). Removing anaconda make the system works
- An alternative way without uninstalling Anaconda, reset python link to default (pointing to python2 from repository)

  ```
  $ ls -l /usr/bin/python
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 10  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
  ```

Comment: Thank you for adding the answer. I don't know why they close this question.

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture , I was one of close voters my reasons: from new user who didn't submit a answer but just mention a work around in comment without any further collaboration, no up-votes on question (but it was new anyway). Now I would change my mind as reason are not valid anymore: it get some interest from other users and also xiawi mention another option with better fit as answer. I'll as for reopening. Thank you.